# Installing dlib to work with facial recognition [dlib has no attribute - get_frontal_face_detector]

Tags: python, face-recognition, dlib

I have been playing with facial recognition a little bit in python, but have been having trouble with getting dlib to work.

I am on a windows 10 environment, working inside of the Pycharm terminal using pip to install everything. When I try to install dlib inside of the terminal, I get a message stating it failed with error code 1.

`Command "C:\Users\Jonathan\PycharmProjects\image_recognition\venv\Scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\Jonathan\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-87y4zmcs\\dlib\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read()
.replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-ug95jqxj\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers C:\Users\Jonathan\PycharmProjects\image
_recognition\venv\include\site\python3.7\dlib" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\Jonathan\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-87y4zmcs\dlib\`

So i opened up the dlib tar.zip file, extracted it, and ran the setup.py and copied the dlib folder inside of that into my site-packages folder.

After that when I try to use the python library face_recognition, I get this error from dlib-
`C:\Users\Jonathan\PycharmProjects\image_recognition\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/Jonathan/PycharmProjects/image_recognition/image_recognition.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jonathan/PycharmProjects/image_recognition/image_recognition.py", line 1, in <module>
    import face_recognition
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\PycharmProjects\image_recognition\face_recognition\__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .api import load_image_file, face_locations, batch_face_locations, face_landmarks, face_encodings, compare_faces, face_distance
  File "C:\Users\Jonathan\PycharmProjects\image_recognition\face_recognition\api.py", line 17, in <module>
    face_detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
AttributeError: module 'dlib' has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector'`

I have installed cmake within the terminal as well before I ran the face_recognition. Any help would be appreciated. I will be able to check this in about 15-20 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution from below link,
[AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'get_frontal_face_detector'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518871/attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-get-frontal-face-detector).

And the face recognition module requires dlib version should be above 19.+.

I'd used 19.17 in my project and installed via conda environment,[How can I solve Error of installation Dlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58286807/how-can-i-solve-error-of-installation-dlib/58624273?noredirect=1#comment103559129_58624273))

Answer (score 0):

This solves my problem :

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute
>   'get_frontal_face_detector'

```
pip uninstall dlib

pip install dlib
```

Os:Macos

Comment: This is a solution exclusively for OSX?